# Are we correctly tagging "scripture" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

Recently, I have found out that scripture tag is not correctly used.

According to the [tag wiki excerpt](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/scripture/info) of the [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture):

> For questions about the holy texts of Hinduism. Please also use a more specific tag (e.g. [vishnu-purana]) if possible.

It says about the questions about scriptures. If there is a specific scripture, then tag it also.

But this is not used properly on many questions. This was tagged to questions which ask about beliefs....

- [Is it a sin to keep dust pan and broomstick together as per Hindu scriptures? If yes, why?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19066/is-it-a-sin-to-keep-dust-pan-and-broomstick-together-as-per-hindu-scriptures-if)

Also to a question asking immortals of Hindu mythology

- [Eight immortals (Include Lord Hanuman) being the Chiranjivi still exist in Kaliyuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18225/eight-immortals-include-lord-hanuman-being-the-chiranjivi-still-exist-in-kaliy)

To a question which is about child marriage:

- [Is child marriage mandatory in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19050/is-child-marriage-mandatory-in-hinduism)

We can find many such examples.

As we can clearly see, these are not about scriptures like Vedas, upanishads, puranas, smritis. They were more or less asking about scriptural reference. It is obvious that an answer will be given from one of the scriptures. Then, why do we need to tag the question scripture separately? Shouldn't we limit this to questions about scriptures like Vedas, Puranas, upanishads etc.,? If every question which asks for scriptural reference is tagged scripture, then almost all the questions will be of that tag only.

What are the tagging guidelines for this?

I have two suggestions:

1. We already have [resource](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource) which is created for asking sources about Hinduism  long ago. We can use that tag instead of the scripture tag when we ask for references. I think the tag wiki of resource should be modified to make it clear.
2. We have [identification-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) which we have used for image identification. We can make it broad and use it for verse identification questions.

Comment: I think it's fine to use the scripture tag for this purpose, to signal to people that you want an answer based on scripture rather than some other kind of source.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Isn't it mandatory that we should provide the answer from authentic sources? If not, that answer will be deleted obviously. So, I think mentioning it explicitly is not required. Tag wiki suggests that the tag  is not from scriptural reference. Changing tag wiki now is a bad idea.  If this tagging is allowed,  scripture tag will be mandatory for all the questions. In most of the cases, It is not the OP who adds it.

Comment: Well, reliable sources are required, but scripture is not the only allowed source.  Scholarly books and journal papers are allowed, for instance.  So someone may want an answer specifically from scripture rather than some other kind of allowed source.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Most of the cases, it is not the OP who tags it. other users with editing privileges are tagging it and adding the phrase "from scriptures" even if the OP doesn't mention in the comments. I also asked for tagging guidelines in the questions. Many are not following the tag wiki.

Comment: I think one should use scripture tag if the question is dealing with scriptures, for the last two questions you pointed out, I don't feel a need for using a scripture tag.

Comment: I think confusion is due to tag description. We can make it clear in tag description.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Changing the tag wiki description is not the solution. Tagging responsibly is the solution. Tag scripture was originally created to tag about scriptures like vedas etc., later it got misused.

Comment: @SreeCharan It's not changing tag description. It's making it unambiguous.

Comment: @Pandya There was no need to all the questions I pointed out. The word "hindu scriptures" is nor added by OP neither he tagged it with scripture. Other users added the word and tagged with scripture. I think post editing should also be taken care.

Comment: @SreeCharan Scripture tag is used for limiting answers only from Hindu scriptures. In general, we also allow words of saints and journals. But looks like original scripture tag description says "this tag should be used only when question is about particular scriptures like, What are vedas?"  and it's totally used for different purpose on large scale, not just misused in editing. In former case, it is not needed. So, description should be made clear.

Comment: Down voted for calling me irresponsible. And, more importantly i don't think that this is any serious problem which is bothering us at the moment. I agree more or less with what Tezz said at the beginning of his answer. Even Pandya's answer says that when a Q is asking about "Which Scripture..? " then scripture tag should be added.

Comment: @Rickross I couldn't remember where did I call you irresponsible? It was not directed to any specific user including you. There is no name callin here. It is a general discussion . Pandya's answer says it is Okay but it also says that tagging every question with scripture is not very good. It will be a problem in a long run. Creating a tag specially for scriptural reference will be a good idea IMO. Because, all the questions will be that tag only.  It is fine to downvote if you disagree but it is not good if someone has called you something.

Comment: "But this is used **irresponsibly** on many questions"...I was talking about this..next u gave examples of such Qs and the first one itself is where my edit is involved. When asking "Which Scriptures ..?" the tag should be used. There is no doubt in this.

Answer (score 4):

It looks many questions are incorrectly tagged with [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture). We should use scripture tag if question deals with scriptures. Out of 3 questions you mentioned, last two don't deserve scripture tag. Most of the questions you've [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/conversation/wrongly-tageed-with-scripture) are wrongly tagged with scripture and scripture tag should be removed from many of those questions.

So, if you find a question that isn't about scriptures in anyway, i.e. **if incorrectly tagged with [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture), then edit it to remove the tag**.

But here one thing need to be pointed out is, many times users tag the question with [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) if he/she is looking for answer explicitly based on scripture i.e looking for scriptural sources. For those questions it is fine to use scripture tag. But tagging every question with [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) just because one wants to emphasise/insist a scriptural source in answer is redundant.

So, **[scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) should only be used if the question is explicitly looking for scriptural base**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
1. I want clarity regarding the second paragraph. Is it a partial yes or a partial no? I got a reply from a user when asked about scripture tag. "every one seeks answer from scriptures only. Using scripture tag is necessary. If not, why would he/she post on our site?" So, if this tag is allowed for scriptural reference, then most of the questions  would be of this tag only. 
2. What about the usage of [tag:identification request] for verse identification question? Isn't that a good idea?

Comment: @SreeCharan We actually allow sources such as Journals or words of saints. Some users may prefer only Hindu Scriptures. "Scriptures is subset of sources." But i think adding Scripture tag for everything may be bad if that particular wants answers only from Hindu Scriptures.

Comment: But i think adding Scripture tag for everything may be bad if that particular wants answers only from Hindu Scriptures. -- What does this mean? @TheDestroyer

Answer (score 2):

In my Opinion We are generally correctly tagging scripture:

1) Tag [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) can be used when a question can be answered with many scriptures.

Eg. I do not agree with removal of scripture tag from question like this:

> [What is the story of Lord Parashurama getting his axe from Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/what-is-the-story-of-lord-parashurama-getting-his-axe-from-lord-shiva)

This question can be answered using many scriptures. Eg. Mahabharata also contains the story of it and also other scripture. So, scripture tag fits for it.

2) Tag [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) can be used when one is Searching for a particular scripture but it is unknown to him/her.

> [Which scripture contains the famous Ganesha Sloka "Vakratunda Mahakaya..."?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11112/which-scripture-contains-the-famous-ganesha-sloka-vakratunda-mahakaya)
>   
>   [Which scripture describes Lakshmi pacifying Narsimha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12308/which-scripture-describes-lakshmi-pacifying-narsimha)

3) Tag [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) may not be used when a question is about particular scripture only. Like:

> [Where does the Linga Purana declare Vishnu to be the supreme soul?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/where-does-the-linga-purana-declare-vishnu-to-be-the-supreme-soul)

But still even in such questions, if scripture tag can be used without removing useful tags, scripture tag can be used as General tag.

4) [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) tag shouldn't be used for the questions which can't be answered through scriptures like questions of saints etc...
Like:

> [Swami Vivekananda Commentaries on Sita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14659/swami-vivekananda-commentaries-on-sita)
>   
>   [Did Swami Vivekananda regularly chant any vedic or Tantric mantras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/did-swami-vivekananda-regularly-chant-any-vedic-or-tantric-mantras)
>   
>   [Does Ramanujacharya believe that inhabitants of Brahmaloka attain Moksha when they die?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8653/does-ramanujacharya-believe-that-inhabitants-of-brahmaloka-attain-moksha-when-th)
>   
>   [Ramanujacharya's Brother](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/ramanujacharyas-brother)

5) But [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) tag can be used to justify behaviour of saints from scriptures like:

> [Was Adi Shankaracharya’s Parakaya Pravesha to learn Kamashastra Dharmic?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15900/was-adi-shankaracharya-s-parakaya-pravesha-to-learn-kamashastra-dharmic)

6) There is no need to remove [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) tag from questions unless there is necessary to add some useful tag. We can use 5 tags and if some tag space is remaining and the question fits for scripture tag then scripture can be used as general tag.

7) Using scripture as general tag is useful because [it lists](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) many questions in a single tag. If a new user or old user who knows many scriptures wants to answer a question then it is helpful for him or her by just going in Scripture tag.

8) Using [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) as general tag is useful because it also enhances search results. Even simple questions which are tagged with scripture show as tagged with Scripture. Thus searchers can also have increased trust in question and answers seeing scripture tag. Like this:
[image]

Comment: I agree with you.Since many new users won't ask to answer questions using scripture but the the answer itself requires the scripture.If you look at most of our answers , we almost all the time provide the answers using Scriptures.

Comment: So i think there is no need to remove Scripture TAG unless its necessary.This site requires to provide answers with Scriptures only.So i also suggest users to add the scripture TAG in the previous questions where its requited and not added when noticed.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Answers in the scriptures is not mandatory. We can add any sources. It's our choice whether or not to give sources from scriptures. Adding every question with scripture where the answers are from scriptures is a bad idea. Read the tag excerpt.  Usage of that tag should be limited to scriptures only. Actually it is other way around *adding* scripture tag is not necessary unless required.

Comment: Here, you are missing excerpt. 1.The question is about a story and this should be tagged if the question is about scripture. It doesn't discuss about any scripture.2. Scripture is redundant here because we have identification request tag. This is the best fit for such questions. Also used in other graduated SE sites 3. Scripture is **not a general tag** if necessary, we can add it. It should be treated like any other tag. 5.Again, missing the tag excerpt, if the question is about a scripture, we can use it. it ain't a general tag. 6.There is no such rule. It is not mandatory to add 5 tags. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 We can remove an irrelevant tag without adding any tag. Actually, it is other way around. Scripture tag **should not be added**  unless a it is related to a scripture. Scripture is not a default tag of our site. We are not scripture.SE 7. This is the main reason I raised this issue. All the questions relevant and irrelevant are being tagged scripture. It is  **very bad to tag every question with scripture because we can find it easily**. 8. Using tag doesn't enhance search results. It is the catchy words,votes,views  which bring new users to our sites. .

Comment: @SS - Yes , I agree with you on "Answering with Scriptures is not mandatory and even not  possible for some questions , like question about some beliefs , philosophy etc.and with your point of adding tag to every question.

Comment: I was just pointing towards the importance of the TAG in most of the answers ,since most of the answers are given with Scriptures no matter tge links are from the original text or refering from  some other site like "Kamkoti peetha" site.

Comment: Tag wise search is an advanced tool which many SE users itself is not aware of. New users will be looking at [tag:scripture] just they look at any other less famous tag. Hence, last point is wrong.  If a tag is present in a question, it signals that there is something relevant to that. If we tag scripture and the question is not about a scripture, then whole point of tagging is abused.For references, we can use a note with bold, italics in the body if the question itself. tag is redundant.example questions in the point 2 are not related to scripture.ID tag is the best for such questions.

Comment: I think it is better to create a [tag:reference] for the questions which look for scriptural reference because, tag badges for scripture should not be available.**I strongly disagree with point 7**. If they want to find a question for late ruse, they can favourite a question forever. It will be visible after deletion too(if they have mod tools).

Comment: I am saying why only scripture tag? We can create a tag for scriptural reference. This would be good. Because there are already 730 questions tagged with scripture. Our site will be dominated with that tag if all are tagged with tag. My point is other tags should also get chance. I am asking for a new tag for scriptural reference and limiting this scripture tag to scripture related questions. Then the users can easily search scriptural reference question.

Comment: After reading the comments thread, i have reversed my vote.

Comment: I agree with ur points although some points will not be agreed upon by all. You see since we can't tag answers so we should allow tagging even Qs which have answers from Scriptures, because that helps in searches and it adds to everyone's knowledge. If we have already exceeded the 5 tag limit and if other tags are more needed than scripture, then of course we can drop it. Also i wholeheartedly agree with ur first line.

Comment: @SS Regarding your comments. All your other comments are just opinions for me (just as my answer is also my opinion) except point 2. Regarding point 2, I say that identification request tag is of high priority in such cases but scripture tag can also be added along with it. And also [many users agree](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/38640?m=38776984#38776984) that tag scripture can be used as General Tag.

Comment: @Tezz Scripture can be used as the general tag in most Qs..if not all.. since Hinduism itself is based primarily on scriptures..so it is expected that it will be the most dominant tag (although right now it is not because of mythology but the irony here is that even mythological stories also come from scripture :P, so this shows the importance of scriptures in Hinduism).. the argument given by the opponent is "but it is getting the most dominant tag so we should stop it from being so!" What?? Why should we stop it? It is expected only.