# Should the "scripture" tag be dropped in awe of "mythology" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

In [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/what-script-did-ganesha-write-the-mahabharata-in), which is about a Hindu *Itihasa* scripture called the *Mahabharata*, OP has tagged it with [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology). Isn't [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) more appropriate?
Because the former tag gives an impression that the stories mentioned in that topic are "myths".

**Question**: When is it more appropriate to drop [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) and retain [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology)?

Comment: See my Meta answer here for the propriety of the [tag:mythology] tag: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/293/36 And the scripture tag would definitely not be appropriate here. The [tag:scripture] tag shouldn't be used any time a question is about some specific scripture. The scripture tag should only be used if 1) the question deals with the nature of scripture in general or possibly 2) if the question is asking for the scriptural basis of something (although 2nd category is under discussion right now.) Mahabharata questions, Vedas questions etc shouldn't be tagged with [tag:scripture].

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Don't agree with ur opinions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My concern about the use of mythology tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/my-concern-about-the-use-of-mythology-tag)

Answer (score 0):

The [post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19643/1049) in Qn, should neither be tagged with [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) nor with [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology).

[scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) should be used **iff**, the Qn specifically expects or discusses a scripture. A very good post has been initiated by @SreeCharan for the awareness on this topic:
[Are we correctly tagging "scripture" tag?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/891/1049)

---

Now, [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology)<sup>#</sup> is not appropriate for this post, because it implies that *MahAbhArata* present in [sacred-texts.com](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm), is a "potential myth" if not a "complete myth". This book is revered by many people across the world and within the site. It should not be termed as a "myth".

One should use this tag only when dealing with "mythology" based sources. However, as of today it seems that we need to define which scriptures belong to "[mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythology)".

<sub># *mythology - collection of myths, especially one belonging to a particular religious or cultural tradition*.</sub>

Comment: Agree with you. Neither mythology nor Scripture suits it.

Comment: I don't agree that scripture is not a suitable tag for the Q. It definitely is. This Q exists only because of the scripture called Mahabharata and it definitely is discussing it in some way. The only circumstance in which the tag can be dropped IMO is when one other tag is more relevant and when the 5 tag limit has been reached. But i agree that mythology does not go with it.

Comment: Also ur edit changed my  Q a lot. Right now it does not seem that i have posted it, it more looks like one of ur Qs. Also content wise too its changed to an extent. The title is redundant, i was not asking that in my original version.

Comment: @Rickross the original Qn was not clear. Feel free to revert the edits. "Scripture" tag should be used mainly when we are specifically asking for scriptures as per decided in accepted answer. I didn't ask such Qn before. :-)

Comment: I was talking about the choice of words etc not  the content.. Anyways right now i don't think that more revisions are needed. Let it be like this.

Comment: @Rickross, the original Qn looked like *"when scripture is the more appropriate tag to use why use mythology instead and drop scripture?"*, that meant you decided that "scripture" tag is certainly more useful at many places over "mythology" tag. Now that would have technically made it "Not a real Qn" as you expressed opinion already. In meta, people will downvote if they don't agree on it. In such scenarios it's better to reverse the Qn & ask it. That would garner the neutral answers. When you have an opinion already then good to put an answer separately.

Comment: @iammilind Yes that was exactly what i was doing.. Besides asking the Q i also made it clear what my opinions are on the issue. 2 users did not like my idea and so they downvoted..that's fine. Apart from looking for opinions of other users through answers or comments i was also looking for how OP can justify his act of not using scripture but using mythology tag. OP clarified in a comment that he did not think scripture is valid tag although its about a scripture. Also mythology tag is for non believers who don't consider the scriptures as depicting true stories. So he must be one..